# Hover com border e imagem CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web  e gostaria que quando não passasse o mouse sobre a imagem, ficasse na tela só a imagem, sem a descrição do produto, o preço  e o border em volta dela.

Imagem sem o efeito do hover.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando eu passe o mouse sobre a imagem gostaria que a imagem ficasse circundada pelo border e aparecesse a descrição do produto,preço e o botão de Saiba mais.

Imagem com hover

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">


            <div class="linha">

                <img src="imagens/camisa_1.JPG" alt="camisa1" class="imagem_teste">
                  <a href="#"  onMouseOver="mostrarElemento('saiba_mais1', 'inline');"  
                     onMouseOut="mostrarElemento('saiba_mais1', 'none');" > 


    <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>

<h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
     <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 

       </a>



        </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.linha{
 border: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
height: 390px;
}

.descricao_produto{
color:black;
font-weight: 700;
}
.preco{
color:red;
}
```

JS

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function mostrarElemento(id, visibilidade) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibilidade;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso sem uso de JavaScript, apenas com CSS:

```css
.linha{
border: 1px solid #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
}

.descricao_produto{
color:black;
font-weight: 700;
}

.preco{
color:red;
}

.linha a{
 display: none;
}

.linha:hover a{
 display: inline-block;
}

.linha:hover{
 border-color: #E0E0DA;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
 <div class="linha">
  <img height="100" src="https://static.hering.com.br//sys_master/images/he3/h01/9378553102366.jpg" alt="camisa1" class="imagem_teste" />
    <br />
  <a href="#">
   <p class="descricao_produto">Calça Jeans Armani</p>
   <h4 class="preco"> A partir de R$134,99</h4>
   <button class="saiba_mais" id="saiba_mais1">SAIBA MAIS</button> 
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DvD ocorreu um problema ao colocar o codigo que você postou a largura do botão saiba mais diminui e não ocupou a largura máxima do border

Comment: @User1999 Meu código foi só um exemplo. Vc deve adaptar no seu código.

Comment: @User1999 Tira o `padding: 10px;`.

Comment: mas então pq na classe      .saiba_mais{
    
     background-color: #00008B;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  
} eu coloquei width 100% mas não ocupou toda a largura do border

Comment: @User1999 Por causa do `padding`.. botei só como exemplo, pode tirar ele.

Comment: eu tirei  .linha {
border: 1px solid #fff;
height: 390px;
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: mas mesmo assim o botão não preencheu o espaço

Comment: @User1999 Fora isso, o resto ficou bom?

Comment: sim DvD funcionou corretamente obrigado

Comment: @User1999 Entao bora ver o lance do botão?

Comment: vamos la, ver esse lance

Comment: @User1999 Vc deve estar usando bootstrap neh?

Comment: sim, estou usando

Comment: @User1999 Eu precisava ver um print de como está e o código HTML disso.. é porque o código da sua pergunta não dá pra reproduzir exatamente o HTML... não tem a classe desse botão etc

Comment: consegui arrumar aqui rs vlw

Comment: @User1999 Blz cara! Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Oculte o item que contem a **class** `saiba_mais` dessa forma:

```
.saiba_mais {
  display: none;
}
```

E para aparecer, você pode pegar qualquer área do mouse que estiver dentro do item que conter a sua **class** `linha` dessa forma:

```
.linha:hover .saiba_mais {
  display: block;
}
```

Para a borda, você coloca `border: none;` para não aparecer a borda na **class** `linha`, e em `linha:hover` que você vai inserir a borda que deseja ao passar com o mouse.

Concluindo o seu **CSS** ficará assim:

```
.saiba_mais {
    display: none;
}

.linha:hover .saiba_mais {
    display: block;
}

.linha{
   border: none;
   height: 390px;
 }

.linha:hover {
    border: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
}

.descricao_produto{
    color:black;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.preco{
    color:red;
}
```

Dessa forma você pode descartar a tag `<a>` e o código em **JS** que não será mais necessário.

Comment: obrigado por responder então Fernando VR, o que eu gostaria de fazer mais não estou conseguindo é quando eu não passar o mouse por cima da imagem quero que não apresenta .linha{
   border: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
   height: 390px;
 }, a borda que fica em volta da imagem.E quando eu passar o mouse por cima da imagem aparecer a linha em volta da imagem junto com button e a descrição e o preço da camiseta

Comment: Ahh sim @User1999, esqueci do border, mas é só colocar ele em `.linha:hover`. O **hover** é sempre para estilos com o mouse por cima. Alterei a minha resposta colocando como deve ficar com o border no hover da linha também.